# Ext.getBody().focus() not working in IE6

Tags: javascript, extjs, ckeditor, focus, internet-explorer-6

`Ext.getBody().focus()` does not appear to be working correctly in IE6.  When a user navigates to a new ExtJS tab, I need to ensure he can no longer type into a CKEditor instance (hidden after navigating to a new tab) in which he might have been typing.  The following code works in FF, but not IE6.

```
for( var instanceName in CKEDITOR.instances ) {
    CKEDITOR.instances[instanceName].focusManager.forceBlur();  // also 
                                                                // not working 
                                                                // in IE6
}
Ext.getBody().focus();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this workaround; I created an input field with zero height and zero width and move the focus to this field to blur a CKEditor field/instance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe all major browsers including IE 6 support the document.activeElement property. If I understand correctly, you need to remove focus from the active form element when the user clicks a tab? Assuming you have access to some sort of event when the tab is clicked, try this:

```
if(document.activeElement) {
    //Call blur() to remove focus from the active (focused) element
    document.activeElement.blur(); 
}
```

If you want to *disable* all input to that field you would want to also give it the "disabled" property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  This doesn't work either - perhaps because the "current" focus is located in an iFrame.

Comment: I believe it would still work, if it's in an iframe you just need to get at *it's* document object:
`window.frames['your_frame'].document.activeElement`